# How can I code a moving circle according to gravitational acceleration?

Tags: python, gravity, threshold, psychopy, acceleration

New programmer here - Used PsychoPy to generate a circle moving across the screen. Super basic, but I want to simulate different realistic acceleration profiles.

Basically I want one of the profiles to be the circle moving at the acceleration of gravity (9.8 m/s^2), and other profiles to be slower or faster than this. I'm not sure how to conceptualize this in code so that it looks representative of gravity but in the confined visual space of a computer monitor.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score -1):

You would create a force acting on the center of the circle.